# Best method for adding a form field in Rails genereated simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

After forgetting a field, when I generated my form I tried to add a field. I changed it manually in the model, view, controller, schema.rb, and activerecord migration. But then it's givving me a NoMethod 'email_address'. Any suggestions how I can generate the field to be applied to all files, as it was when intially generated? thanks.

Comment: was rake db:migration successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to make changes to the timestamp_xxx file but when you rake db:migrate, it may lead to some errors as the table is already created.

What you can do is manually add the new column.

```
$ rails db
```

rails db figures out which database you’re using and drops you into whichever command line interface you would use with it. Here, you can alter the table and add the new column to the table.

For eg, in db2 you will do something like:

```
$ alter table <table name> add column <column name> <type>
```

Once the new column is added, you should not get that no method error

Comment: I enterend this 'alter table <purchases> add column <email> <string> ;' and I am retunred with an "error: near "<": syntax error.
And I did rechange them all, to just display 'email.' instead of 'email_address.'

Comment: I got it! Thank you. Had to look up syntax for sqlite

Comment: So for me it was <sqlite> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name ;